# UITableView Exception After Rendering

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting this error when a load a UITableView. It's occurring after the nib loads, but before either the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection` or other related methods are called.

The object it is backed onto is empty, but it still occurs when there is an object there (it's an NSMutableArray).

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1860.2/UITableViewSupport.m:263

2011-08-12 12:24:00.616 WheresNext[684:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to resolve row for index path: <NSIndexPath 0x1d18f0> 2 indexes [0, 1]'
```

This doesn't however occur in the Simulator, only on devices.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the delegate and datasoruce set up properly on your tableview?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs often when it exists an inconsistency between the rows you add to your TableView and the number of rows return by `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: When forcefully returning 0, the error occurs. Shouldn't it simply render nothing when that's what's returned?

Comment: No. There is an inside assertion that continuously verify coherency. That's why exception is named: NSInternalInconsistencyException :-)

Comment: Where else does it check against? The same object is used for the `UITableViewDelegate` + `UITableViewDataSource` delegates.

Comment: As an instance, every time you call insertSections:withRowAnimation: or insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: next calls to tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: or numberOfSectionsInTableView: returns should reflect the new values. Same things for deletion methods

Comment: Hmm. I'm not calling either of those. As I was using the count of `numberOfRowsInSection` to get the tableView to fill. Is that a bad thing to do?

Comment: In fact, it could be as simple as your code doesn't provide the cell for the indexPath 0 1 in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method...

Comment: @gsempe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2405/discussion-between-nickcharlton-and-gsempe)

Comment: @Adriana Unfortunately, I didn't. I was having issues with Xcode also, so put it down to this. If you find a solution, it'd be great to close off the question.

Comment: @nickcharlton I found a solution to my problem, but unfortunately I don't think it will help you much because the scenario is different, although the error was similar. Anyway, you can have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880294/multiple-nsfetchedresultscontroller-didchangeobject