# Multiple NSFetchedResultsController - didChangeObject

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` which uses 2 `NSFetchedResultsControllers`. Each `NSFetchedResultsController` has only one section. However, the table has 4 sections. I populate the 4th section of the table with the results of one of the `NSFetchedResultsControllers`. Everything works fine so far. But if the user deletes the first cell on the first section, the `NSFetchedResultsControllers` are changed. The rows in the last section of the table might be deleted. When this method is called:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        NSLog(@"section: %d, row: %d", [newIndexPath section], [newIndexPath row]);

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
...
}
```

The section is always 0 because it's the section of the `NSFetchedResultsControllers`. Thus, the section doesn't match the correct one on the table view.

Is there a workaround? I would basically like to change the section of a `NSFetchedResultsController` to 3 instead of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround, but it would be nice to have a prettier solution.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
if (newIndexPath != nil && controller == self.fetchedXController) {
    newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[newIndexPath row] inSection:3];
    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] == nil) {
        type = NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert;
    }
}
if (indexPath != nil && controller == self.fetchedDomainsController) {
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] inSection:3];
}

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] atIndexPath:newIndexPath];
        break;
...
```